# NLog in different versions for multiple projects

Tags: c#, nlog

In my project I am using NLog assembly with file version 4.6.6. My application is being loaded by the external app (no access to the source code) which also uses NLog with file version 4.7.2.

Everything from the external app and my app is being logged correctly. The strange thing that I am facing is that in my app I add the logging rules:

```
        var uniqueLogName = "mylogger" + Guid.NewGuid();
        var rule = new LoggingRule(uniqueLogName, ConvertLogLevel(SelectedLogLevel), myFileTarget);
        LogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

        var uniqueObjectsLogName = "myObjectslogger" + Guid.NewGuid();
        var objectsRule = new LoggingRule(uniqueObjectsLogName, ConvertLogLevel(SelectedLogLevel), myObjectTarget);
        LogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(objectsRule);
```

And for some reason I am getting folders with these rule names created on C drive (see the link below) and honestly, I don't even know where to look for the issue. Can this be some sort of configuration on the NLog?

[image]

Comment: You could try and enable NLog InternalLogger on Debug-Level to see what FileTarget is creating those directories: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: Will do, thanks : ) I will update topic once I get more info.

Comment: Please share the config of myFileTarget and myObjectTarget, the filename configured for those targets is probably the issue.

Comment: The file name is as visible on the screen: mylogger + Guid. And this is configured directly in the code. The other NLog is configured in file. I decided to put some ignore filters on the NLog.config file and it did the trick.